# Margin not working on input

Tags: php, html, css

I'm trying to learn mysqli and so I thought I'd put what I learned to the test. I'm just trying to get the mark up right for a login page to do some simple query's. So the first thing I did was set up a form to collect the first name and password from the user. I wanted a little space in between the two inputs (and another for submit). Since they are "stacked" on top of each other I thought I would do it with this code (the css does connect)

```
`#logininput{
 margin-top:5 px;   
}`
```

really simple easy css. But it did nothing so I tried setting in to margin instead of margin-top. Still nothing. Here is the markup used.

```
<head>
   <title>Login</title> 
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>

    <form action="index.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" id="logininput" name="Fname"><br/>
        <input type="text" id="logininput" name="Lname"><br/>
        <input type="submit" id="logininput"name="loginS"><br/>
    </form>

</body>
```

Anyone know why it is not working? (as a note there is a pair of php tags with a require in them for connecting to a DB)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that there is a space between the value of margin an the units. It should be

```
margin-top: 5px;
```

without the space between '5' and 'px'

Comment: Thank you. I was not aware that was a problem.

Comment: But you should also see @taxicala's answer because using id multiple times isn't allowed either.

Answer (score 1):

You should use class instead when you want to style more than one element, with id, only the first occurrence will get the styles:

```
.logininput {
 margin-top: 5px;   
}

<form action="index.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" class="logininput" name="Fname"><br/>
    <input type="text" class="logininput" name="Lname"><br/>
    <input type="submit" class="logininput" name="loginS"><br/>
</form>
```